# How to modify existing stored procedure to accept list of UDT and change the method accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SQW].[usp_AddSqaeCapacityAssignHrsData_CMS]
  @ActionType varchar(10)='create',
  @UserPrincipalName varchar(500) = NULL,
  @Id INT = NULL,
  @DataFor VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
  @AreaName varchar(50) = NULL,
  @Region [SQW].[udt_RegionList_CMS] READONLY,
  @CapacityHrs INT = NULL,
  @NoofFolderCapacity INT = NULL,
  @PerFolderCapacityHrs INT = NULL,
  @CompetenciesParams [SQW].[udt_CompetencyList_CMS] READONLY 
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN T1;
     BEGIN
         IF @ActionType='edit'
         BEGIN
          UPDATE SQW.DimSQAECapacity SET CapacityHrs=NULL WHERE CapacityHrs IS NOT NUll AND CapacityHrs=@CapacityHrs AND Region =@Region AND Competency NOT IN (SELECT Competency FROM @CompetenciesParams)
         END
        MERGE SQW.DimSQAECapacity AS t  
           USING (  
                  SELECT * FROM @CompetenciesParams 
                  ) AS s ON t.Region =@Region AND t.Competency = s.Competency
        WHEN MATCHED THEN  
               UPDATE SET  
                t.CapacityHrs = @CapacityHrs, t.IsActive=1, t.ModifiedDate = GETUTCDATE(), ModifiedBy = @UserPrincipalName
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
            INSERT (  
                    Area,Region,Competency,CapacityHrs,NoofFolderCapacity,PerFolderCapacityHrs,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,ModifiedDate,ModifiedBy
                    )  
            VALUES (  
                    @AreaName,@Region,s.Competency,@CapacityHrs,@NoofFolderCapacity,NULL,GETUTCDATE(),@UserPrincipalName,GETUTCDATE(),@UserPrincipalName
                   );  
     END
```

I have recently added [SQW].[udt_RegionList_CMS] for @regions as per the requirement and below are the complications I'm facing when I try to modify the further Stored procedure ,

1. The above code works when multiple competencies are passed then it will check the DB ,if the details are exist then it will update the table else insert the value .
2. Now the code should be modified to accept when they pass the value as {'America' ,'Africa'} as region and {Competency1,Competency2} as Competencies .

   - The DB already contains the data for the combination {'America','Competency2'} then the existing value should be modified .
   - The rest combinations {'America','Competency1'},{'Africa','Competency1'},{'Africa','Competency2'} should be inserted into the table .In this case how the stored procedure should be modified ?.

Could anyone help me on the above statement?

Comment: This is not Oracle code. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @MT0 I'm using SSMS

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is a client application, what RDBMS are you connecting to? (I'm assuming SQL Server - in which case why did you tag Oracle and MySQLi?)

Comment: You can cross join your input tables and then join them against the merge table to do what you need to do. If you have problem with merge, i suggest avoiding it and rewrite it using UPDATE/INSERT